# Best Python library for statistical inference

Tags: python, statistics

I'm curious if anyone has Python library suggestions for inferential statistics. I'm currently reading [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/), which uses R for the example code, but ideally I'd like to use Python as well.

Most of my data experience is with Pandas, Matplotlib, and Sklearn doing predictive modeling.

So far I've found [statsmodels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels). Is this what is recommended or is there something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/) is a good, and fairly standard, package to statistics.

For Bayesian interference you can go with [PyMC](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/) - see as in [Cam Davidson-Pilon, Probabilistic Programming & Bayesian Methods for Hackers](http://camdavidsonpilon.github.io/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/).